# Does Atlassian Stash provide pastebin/GitHub gist like functionality?

Tags: product, gist, bitbucket-server

From their public [product description of Stash](http://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview) I can't tell whether they provide such an functionality.

Can anyone tell me if Stash has [pastebin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) / [gist like](http://gist.github.com/) functionality?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about product support for a third-party product, not programming.

Comment: You're welcome,  @Martijn Pieters! Today I'd ask this in the [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) Stack, but it does exist only for 1yr. :) Maybe it could be migrated instead?

Comment: It can't; only posts less than 60 days old can be migrated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Atlassian Stash does not currently offer pastebin/gist-like functionality. A New Feature request has been opened to add it: [STASH-2628 Code snippet sharing](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2628) requesting it.

As someone mentioned below, there is [now a paid plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.simplenia.stash.plugins.snippets) (not from Atlassian) that provides pastebin/gist like functionality to Stash.

Answer (score 2):

It's not included in Stash. However, there is a paid addon which provides this feature. See https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.simplenia.stash.plugins.snippets